# C++ comparing string array elements

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm new to c++ and as my first assignment was to make a game of reversi, but I'm having problems when it comes to changing the pieces. I've tried to compare the string elements but nothing happens. Here's the code to show you what's the issue.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void displayTop();



int main() {
    string board [8][8] = {

        " "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ",
        " "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ",
        " "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ",
        " "," "," ","W","B"," "," "," ",
        " "," "," ","B","W"," "," "," ",
        " "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ",
        " "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ",
        " "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ",

    };
    displayTop();
    cout << endl;

    for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++){
        cout << "   ";

        for (int column = 0; column < 8; column++){
            cout << board[row][column] << "    ";
        }
        cout << endl;
        displayTop();
        cout << endl << endl;
    }
    if(board[0][0] == " "){
        board[0][1] = "W";
    }
}
void displayTop(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        cout << "+----";
    }
    cout << endl;

}
```

Comment: "nothing happens". What do you expect to happen? You never print out the contents of the board.

Comment: Not your bug, but - why are you hardcoding `board[0][0]`? Btw, your board doesn't need to be an array of strings. Why not use `char board [8][8]`?  Do you really want to `displayTop();` once per row? When your code is complete, ask others to review it for you at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please tell us what is expected.

Comment: That "nothing happens" isn't really helping us much. But comparing a string variable to a const char* with the == operator is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comparaison is after the display of the board, that's maybe why you did not see any change.

Why dont you use char instead of string ?

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    void displayTop();

    int main() {
        char board [8][8] = {

            ' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',
            ' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',
            ' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',
            ' ',' ',' ','W','B',' ',' ',' ',
            ' ',' ',' ','B','W',' ',' ',' ',
            ' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',
            ' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',
            ' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',

        };

        if(board[0][0] == ' '){
            board[0][1] = 'W';
        }

        displayTop();
        cout << endl;

            for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++){
                cout << "   ";

            for (int column = 0; column < 8; column++){
                cout << board[row][column] << "    ";
            }
            cout << endl;
            displayTop();
            cout << endl << endl;
        }
    }

    void displayTop(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
            cout << "+----";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```